# Errors in Android Studio myfirstapp : Gradle errors

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to follow along with the official Android tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) but I'm failing miserably. Everything worked OK until I needed to add a second Activity. First, the Activity I created in Android Studio does not show up in my list of java files. I clicked New -> Activity and nothing appeared. To get around this I opened up Windows Explorer and copied/renamed MainActivity.java to DisplayMessageActivity.java and added the code in the tutorial.

After following along the app does not run and I get multiple "Gradle" errors such as:

```
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Activity
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class Bundle
```

What do I need to fix in order to get this to run? Here is the relevant code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    }

}
```

Display MessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);

        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create an activity, make sure you insert it into mainifest.xml as well, so your manifest should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MessageActivity>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hm...still getting the errors. I edited your code to `android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity" />` but I still get the same errors

Comment: make sure your java file and ClassName have the same names

Answer (score 0):

On each error you got (on red as on image) go and press Alt+Enter to import missing classes or declare the variables.

Please note that all files (.java) have to be not red underlined if they are error free.

[image: Error]

[image: After Alt+Enter class imported. No error.]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some tutorial´s  names of classes´s changed. then you need put the name your Activity before the variable "extra_message" like that MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE

on the main Activity put...
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

or simple use any value. like that 
String message = intent.getStringExtra('xxx');

Answer (score -1):

Go on through the tutorial, you'll be taught to create one later.